# Rename hyperlinks in query result in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

Here is my query

```
 {{#ask: [[Category:Pages]]
   |mainlabel = Link
   |? volume = Volume
   |? page = Volume page
   |? title = Title
   |limit = 3
 }}
```

The result table is like ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IM7S.png))

```
Link            Volume    Volume page    Title
HPB-SB-1-1      1         1              Article A
HPB-SB-1-10     1         10             Article B
HPB-SB-1-100    1         100            Article C
```

Where each cell in Link column is actually a hyperlink leading to the corresponding page. What I need to do is somehow rename the cells in `Link` column to still be hyperlinks but have name of ones from `Title` column. So the result table become:

```
Link            Volume    Volume page 
Article A       1         1        
Article B       1         10        
Article C       1         100
```

Does anyone knows how can this be achieved with Semantic Mediawiki? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [template](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Archive:Template_format) format:

```
{|
! Link !! Volume !! Volume page
{{#ask: [[Category:Pages]]
   |mainlabel = Link
   |? volume = Volume
   |? page = Volume page
   |? title = Title
   |limit = 3
   |format = template
   |template = table_row
 }}
|}
```

where `Template:table_row` is:

```
{{!}}-
{{!}} [{{{1}}}} {{{4}}}] {{!}}{{!}} {{{2}}} {{!}}{{!}} {{{3}}}
```